# Add RegEx pattern inside JSON string using JSON_QUERY()

Tags: json, sql-server, serialization, json-query

I have RegEx details table and I want to make array object. I am trying to make JSON using `JSON_QUERY()` then I getting error like:

> "JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '"' is
> found".

It's only getting when I use RegEx pattern (which has \ slash) as JSON property value.

Sample data:

```
DECLARE @RegExData AS TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, label VARCHAR(100), ValidationName VARCHAR(100), ValidationPattern VARCHAR(100))

INSERT @RegExData(label, ValidationName, ValidationPattern)
VALUES('LABEL1', 'NumberOnlyEXP','/^[0-9\s]*$/')

INSERT @RegExData(label, ValidationName, ValidationPattern)
VALUES('LABEL1', 'DecimalEXP','/^(\d+(\.\d+)?)$/')

INSERT @RegExData(label, ValidationName, ValidationPattern)
VALUES('LABEL2', 'DecimalWithZeroEXP','/^(\d+(\.\d+)?)$/')

INSERT @RegExData(label, ValidationName, ValidationPattern)
VALUES('LABEL2', 'AlphabetOnlyEXP',' /^[a-zA-Z]*$/')
```

Statement with error:

```
SELECT
    JSON_QUERY('[' + STRING_AGG('{"ValidationName":' +  CHAR(34) + CAST(ValidationName AS VARCHAR(100)) +  CHAR(34) +
        ',' + '"ValidationPattern":' + CHAR(34) + CAST(ValidationPattern AS VARCHAR(100))+ CHAR(34) +
    '}' , ',') + ']')SELECT AS* data
FROM @RegExData
FOR JSON PATH
```

Comment: SQL Server 2019

Comment: @DeepThumar, what final output do you want to generate? The actual reason for this error is that JSON_QUERY() expects a valid JSON content. `SELECT ValidationName, ValidationPattern FROM @RegExData FOR JSON PATH` is probably an option here.

Comment: @Zhorov, I want this JSON to be inside an array. I want to receive the following output: 
**[
  {
    "label": "Max Fare Change Per Seat:",
    "data": [
      {
        "value": 0,
        "label": "Percentage",
        "DefaultValue": "N/A",
        "ValidationType": "DecimalEXP",
  "ValidationPattern":"/^(\d+(\.\d+)?)$/"
        "MaxLength": "3"
      },
      {
        "value": 0,
        "label": "Rupees",
        "DefaultValue": "N/A",
        "ValidationType": "NumberOnlyEXP",
  "ValidationPattern":"/^[0-9\s]*$/"
        "MaxLength": "10"
      }
    ]
  }
]**

Answer (score 1):

I tried a new code, but there is a double \ (backslash) issue in RegEx pattern.
Here is sample data and code with output.

```
DECLARE @RegExData AS TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, label VARCHAR(100), ValidationName VARCHAR(100), ValidationPattern VARCHAR(100))
INSERT @RegExData(label, ValidationName, ValidationPattern) VALUES('LABEL1', 'NumberOnlyEXP','/^[0-9\s]*$/')
INSERT @RegExData(label, ValidationName, ValidationPattern) VALUES('LABEL1', 'DecimalEXP','/^(\d+(\.\d+)?)$/')
INSERT @RegExData(label, ValidationName, ValidationPattern) VALUES('LABEL2', 'DecimalWithZeroEXP','/^(\d+(\.\d+)?)$/')
INSERT @RegExData(label, ValidationName, ValidationPattern) VALUES('LABEL2', 'AlphabetOnlyEXP',' /^[a-zA-Z]*$/')


SELECT * FROM @RegExData

SELECT LABEL
 , (SELECT t1.ValidationName AS ' label', t1.ValidationPattern AS ' value'
    FROM @RegExData t1
    WHERE  t1.label = t.label
    FOR JSON PATH
    ) as data
FROM @RegExData t
GROUP BY label
FOR JSON AUTO
```

[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4BMi.png)

Comment: It's correct. It's *supposed* to escape the `\ ` because it has special meaning in JSON. When a parser reads it then it will be unescaped correctly Eg https://dbfiddle.uk/JILBNCl3